# Make a nested JSON from online zipped CSV

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv, python-itertools

I'm fairly new to Python and I need to make a nested JSON out of an online zipped CSV file using standard libraries *only* and *specifically* in python 2.7. I've figured out the accessing and unzipping the file but am having some trouble with the parsing. Basically, I need to make a JSON output that contains three high-level elements for each primary key:

1. The primary key (which is made up of columns 0,2,3&4)
2. A dictionary that is a time series of the observed values for that PK (ie: date: observed value)
3. A dictionary of metadata (The product, flowtype, units,and ideally a nested time series of the quality for each observed point.

   ```
   from StringIO import StringIO 
   from urllib import urlopen 
   from zipfile
   import ZipFile from datetime 
   import datetime import itertools as it 
   import csv 
   import sys

   url = urlopen("https://www.jodidata.org/_resources/files/downloads/gas-data/jodi_gas_csv_beta.zip")
   myzip = ZipFile(StringIO(url.read())) 
   with myzip.open('jodi_gas_beta.csv','r' ) as myCSV:         
       #Read the data  
       reader=csv.DictReader(myCSV)
       #Sort the data by PK + Time for timeseries
       reader=sorted(reader,key=lambda row: row['REF_AREA'],row['ENERGY_PRODUCT'],row['FLOW_BREAKDOWN'],row['UNIT_MEASURE'],row['TIME_PERIOD']))

   #initialize dictionaries for output
   myData=[] 
   keys=[] 
   groups=[] 

   #limiting to first 200 rows for testing ONLY
   for k, g in it.groupby(list(it.islice(reader,200)),key=lambda row: row['REF_AREA'],row['ENERGY_PRODUCT'],row['FLOW_BREAKDOWN'],row['UNIT_MEASURE'])):
       keys.append(k)
       groups.append(list(g))
       myData.append({'MyPK': ''.join(k),  #captures the PKs
           'TimeSeries' : dict((zip(e['TIME_PERIOD'],e['OBS_VALUE']))) for e in g], #Not working properly, want a time series dictionary here
           #TODO: Dictionary of metadata here (with nested time series, if possible)})

   #TODO: Output as a JSON string
   ```

So, the Result should look something like this:

```
{
    "myPK": "AENATGASEXPLNGM3",
    "TimeSeries":[
      ["2015-01", 756],
      ["2015-02", 572],
      ["2015-03", 654]
    ],
    "Metadata":{
      "Country":"AE",
      "Product":"NATGAS",
      "Flow":"EXPLNG",
      "Unit":"M3",
      "Quality:[
          ["2015-01", 3],
          ["2015-02", 3],
          ["2015-03", 3]
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If your code is building the structure you want, almost all of it is irrelevant to the [mcve]. Just show us an example of what ends up in `myData` and what you want to do with it (the one thing you _haven't_ given us). If there is a problem with your code, on the other hand, you have to explain what that problem is. (Also, it has to actually run up to the point where the problem happens—your posted code will just raise a `SyntaxError` on that `from zipfile` line.)

Comment: Anyway, you seem to have found the `csv`, `ZipFile`, etc. modules in the stdlib. There's another one called `json`, which does exactly what you want.

Comment: I know the JSON library can help with the final dump formatting, but making the data parse into the proper timeseries subgroupings is what Im having difficulty with.  Just updated to show output example.

Comment: OK, then what do you have now? What's in `myData` that's different from this? You need to actually tell us what your problem is, instead of making us guess based on the `TODO` comments in your code and the things you didn't say you knew how to do in the text.

Comment: In my data #1 is fine - But I can't seem to get the nested dictionary time series of data points to represent properly (this is the #2 in the three outputs) - its just not a time series dictionary and I'm not sure what I''m doing wrong (If you run the code you will see). I haven't yet attempted #3 since it builds on getting #2 right.

Comment: Looks like I copied the url incorrectly before - I just updated the code so it doesn't break and gets up to the point where I was having the problems with the parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't appear to have put much effort into solving the problem yourself, here's something I think does what you want. It makes use of the [`operator.itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function to simplify retrieving a series of different items from the various containers (such as `list`s and `dict`s).

I also modified the code to more closely follow the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

```
import datetime
import csv
from operator import itemgetter
import itertools as it
import json
from StringIO import StringIO
import sys
from urllib import urlopen
from zipfile import ZipFile

# Utility.
def typed_itemgetter(items, callables):
    """ Like operator.itemgetter() but also applies corresponding callable to
        each retrieved value if it's not None. Creates and returns a function.
    """
    return lambda row: [f(value) if f else value
                            for value, f in zip(itemgetter(*items)(row), callables)]

url = urlopen("https://www.jodidata.org/_resources/files/downloads/gas-data/jodi_gas_csv_beta.zip")
myzip = ZipFile(StringIO(url.read()))
with myzip.open('jodi_gas_beta.csv', 'r' ) as myCSV:
    reader = csv.DictReader(myCSV)
    primary_key = itemgetter('REF_AREA', 'ENERGY_PRODUCT', 'FLOW_BREAKDOWN', 'UNIT_MEASURE',
                             'TIME_PERIOD')
    reader = sorted(reader, key=primary_key)

# Limit to first 200 rows for TESTING.
reader = [row for row in it.islice(reader, 200)]

# Group the data by designated keys (aka "primary key").
keys, groups = [], []
keyfunc = itemgetter('REF_AREA', 'ENERGY_PRODUCT', 'FLOW_BREAKDOWN', 'UNIT_MEASURE')
for k, g in it.groupby(reader, key=keyfunc):
    keys.append(k)
    groups.append(list(g))

# Create corresponding JSON-like Python data-structure.
myData = []
for i, group in enumerate(groups):
    result = {'myPK': ''.join(keys[i]),
              'TimeSeries': [
                    typed_itemgetter(('TIME_PERIOD', 'OBS_VALUE'),
                                     (None, lambda x: int(float(x))))(row)
                        for row in group]
             }
    metadata = dict(zip(("Country", "Product", "Flow", "Unit"), keys[i]))
    metadata['Quality'] = [typed_itemgetter(
                            ('TIME_PERIOD', 'ASSESSMENT_CODE'), (None, int))(row)
                                for row in group]
    result['Metadata'] = metadata
    myData.append(result)

# Display the data to be turned into JSON.
from pprint import pprint
print('myData:')
pprint(myData)

# To create JSON format output, use something like:
import json
with open('myData.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(myData, fp, indent=2)
```

Beginning portion of the output printed:

```
myData:
[{'Metadata': {'Country': 'AE',
               'Flow': 'EXPLNG',
               'Product': 'NATGAS',
               'Quality': [['2015-01', 3],
                           ['2015-02', 3],
                           ['2015-03', 3],
                           ['2015-04', 3],
                           ['2015-05', 3],
                           ['2015-06', 3],
                           ['2015-07', 3],
                           ['2015-08', 3],
                           ['2015-09', 3],
                           ['2015-10', 3],
                           ['2015-11', 3],
                           ['2015-12', 3],
                           ['2016-01', 3],
                           ['2016-02', 3],
                           ['2016-04', 3],
                           ['2016-05', 3]],
               'Unit': 'M3'},
  'TimeSeries': [['2015-01', 756],
                 ['2015-02', 572],
                 ['2015-03', 654],
                 ['2015-04', 431],
                 ['2015-05', 681],
                 ['2015-06', 683],
                 ['2015-07', 751],
                 ['2015-08', 716],
                 ['2015-09', 830],
                 ['2015-10', 580],
                 ['2015-11', 659],
                 ['2015-12', 659],
                 ['2016-01', 742],
                 ['2016-02', 746],
                 ['2016-04', 0],
                 ['2016-05', 0]],
  'myPK': 'AENATGASEXPLNGM3'},
 {'Metadata': {'Country': 'AE',
               'Flow': 'EXPPIP',
               'Product': 'NATGAS',
               'Quality': [['2015-01', 3],
                           ['2015-02', 3],
                           ['2015-03', 3],
                           ['2015-04', 3],
                           ['2015-05', 3],
                           ['2015-06', 3],
                           ['2015-07', 3],
                           ['2015-08', 3],
                           ['2015-09', 3],
                           ['2015-10', 3],
                           ['2015-11', 3],
                           ['2015-12', 3],
                           ['2016-01', 3],
                           ['2016-02', 3],
                           ['2016-03', 3],
                           ['2016-04', 3],
    # etc, etc...
]
```